# install application for all users using vs2005 setup project

Tags: deployment, desktop, installation, projects-and-solutions

How do i install application for all users using vs2005 setup project, i have enabled install all users property in setup project to true, but there is no impact after installation. my application not loaded in other user accounts (shows an error message).

Answer (score 0):

May be! you will find some useful information from this thread - [VS2008 Setup Project: Shared (By All Users) Application Data Files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76760/vs2008-setup-project-shared-by-all-users-application-data-file)