# How disable an application to be installed for all users?

Tags: visual-studio, installation

I am trying to make an application installer, it needs to install an amount of read/writeable files to user application data.

But when i install that only happens for the user installing the project. The instalation wizard aks if the application should be installed of only the current user or everyone, how can I prevent my user selecting everyone ?

or how to add files to an installer, accessable to all users ?.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> To specify mandatory per-user
>   installation
>
> 1. In Solution Explorer, select the
>      deployment project.
> 2. In the Properties window, select the
>      InstallAllUsers property and set it to
>      false.
> 3. On the View menu, point to Editor, and
>      then click User Interface.
> 4. Under the Install node, select the
>      Installation Folder node.
> 5. In the Properties window, select the
>      InstallAllUsersVisible property and
>      set it to false.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/445kc47k(VS.90).aspx

Info about files shared by all users :
[VS2008 Setup Project: Shared (By All Users) Application Data Files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76760/vs2008-setup-project-shared-by-all-users-application-data-files)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% clear on your question -- perhaps there are 2 questions here.  I can suggest:

1 - There is a Windows Installer property CommonAppDataFolder:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367992(v=VS.85).aspx

You could store data here that would be available to all users of the machine.

2 - The ALLUSERS property manages how applications get installed per-user or per-machine:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367559(v=VS.85).aspx

If you set ALLUSERS in your install package, you can force per-user or per-machine.

Comment: Beware that CommonAppDataFolder is *not* writable after install.  Which I assume is the real problem here.

Comment: Yup, the writability is my main consern here.

In terms of the ALLUSERS, how is that settable through a set up project in visual studio ? The property InstallAllUsers is not persistant as the user can change it when installing.