# Allow to save data on access db using vb or c# on win7 or vista?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access, setup-project

I want to install my app or (just access db)to AppData folder to enable write for it.
so, how can I do that in setup project.
Is there just parameter or should I wirte custom action.
Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Thx Guys, here you can find a beauti answer:

**I solved it this way. I kept the database file (.sdf) in the same folder as where the application is installed (Application Folder). On the security tab in the properties window for the main project, i checked the "Enable ClickOnce Security Settings" and selected "This is a full trust application", rebuilt and ran the setup. After that no security problem
I am using Visual Studio 2008 and Windows Vista**

in this link:
[VS2008 Setup Project: Shared (By All Users) Application Data Files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76760/vs2008-setup-project-shared-by-all-users-application-data-files)