# vb.net File installed in User Profile not available to all users

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019, setup-project

I am getting this Warning when I Build my Setup File
WARNING: File 'c.ico' should not be installed into a User's Profile folder because it may not be available to all users

In the project I have c.ico in two places and have built the project two times using each location

"SourcePath" = "8:..\TestIcon\Resources\c.ico" "TargetName" = "8:c.ico"
"SourcePath" = "8:..\TestIcon\c.ico" "TargetName" = "8:c.ico"
Please NOTE that Resources is a Folder I created it is not the folder under Resources.resx

If I understand this WARNING it says if you run this application on another computer the c.icon will not be found
I do not have another computer to test this on so the question is

**Is that WARNING true the application will not run on another computer?

If So how do I fix the issue?**
I am curious as why I can not rename or name the shortcut "Primary output from TestIcon"
I ask this because in a tutorial the user would rename the shortcut It seems logical to not permit renaming to avoid naming conflicts

For Clarity I am Including a Screen Shot

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Not answering the question, but you can [Get a Windows 10 development environment](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/virtual-machines/) virtual machine for free from Microsoft.

Comment: @AndrewMorton When i installed VS 2019 I got a message Windows 10 Environment was installed I guess I need to know how to use it Thanks for the Advice I just took a look see and is this going Bye Bye or it is only FREE till This VM will expire on 8/11/20.

Comment: The VM will expire, but you can create another one (for free).

Comment: I haven't done any setup projects in VS2019, but [VS2008 Setup Project: Shared (By All Users) Application Data Files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76760/1115360) may have the information you need, or just other information that is useful.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I noticed that setting ME ONLY or All Users I selected ME ONLY when I did the build VS2019 is sometimes very different than other versions I watched to videos on Setup one 2019 and the other 2010 Screens are way different But the real puzzle for me was the 2019 guy would rename the shortcuts and just reused the value in the App Folder each time for the other folders I used Inno Setup when I was using VB 6 it took a while to learn but worked great

Comment: I suspect it is unlikely that anyone else will watch the video to give you an answer, but they couldn't even if they wanted to without a link to that video ;)

Comment: @AndrewMorton Here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-oIf6lGdaik and HERE https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tiHBwAp_Kz4